# Omit lines of incorrrect length

Tags: grep

i have a file as below.

```
0033613766442
007969947485
01027709100
0113204909
01132049819
01132100218
01132127941
01132179212
```

I would like a command to only display the lines which contain 11 characters exactly?.

Comment: What code do you have so far? Please post.

Answer (score 1):

You can say:

```
grep -P '^.{11}$' filename
```

That'd print lines that contain 11 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` you can do like this

```
awk 'length($0)==11' file
01027709100
01132049819
01132100218
01132127941
01132179212
```

---

Or this short variation

```
awk 'NF==11' FS= file
```

Comment: `length` without argument by default is length of `$0`, so `length==11` would go.